# UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/plugin/compiler/TestCompilerMojo

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I am new to Maven. On Eclipse I am getting following error in pom.xml :-

"Multiple annotations found at this line:

- CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-testCompile: TypeNotPresentException: Type 
  org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo not present: UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/plugin/compiler/TestCompilerMojo : Unsupported 
  major.minor version 51.0
- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: 
  test-compile)
- maven-enforcer-plugin (goal ""enforce"") is ignored by m2e.

I have upgraded from Java 1.6 to Java 1.8. So I also started using new maven 3.5.2. And updated maven-compiler-plugin from 2.3.2 to 3.7.0 in super-pom.
Kindly help in debugging.

pom.xml where I am getting error:  tag

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.abcdef.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>dev-main</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
```

Note: I am able to build successfully on git bash. The error is only shown in pom.xml in Eclipse.

Comment: What is the `mvn -v`?

Comment: Could you update your post to show pom.xml (or at least the relevant portion)? Also, if you go to **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs** what are the details for the checked entry in the list of installed JREs?

Comment: Does you project compile on command ? If you have not tested yet do that first...

Comment: 1) $ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T09:58:13+02:00)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.5.2
Java version: 1.8.0_162, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to be due to older version of m2e eclipse plugin.You can upgrade the m2e plugin or move to neon(if already not moved) as you are on Java 8 and Neon is suitable for it.

Comment: Yes it solved my problem.I was using Luna m2e 1.5. I just moved to Neon with m2e 1.7 and it solved the error :)